# Cordova Storage Location For Large Local Video Files

Tags: html, cordova, video, video.js, visual-studio-cordova

I am doing a simple cordova app using a large local html5 video.  The large local video is 1.76GB.  I have tried the assets directory of www/videos/myfile.mp4  and the raw directory of /platforms/android/res/raw/myfile. I am referencing the directories in the  tag correctly.  I can get a 225MB video file working in either directory.  A 452MB file works only in the raw folder but not the videos folder.  I can get the 1.76GB file working if I reference it from external SD storage.  I don't want the files to have to live on the SD card for security of the video file.  So some locations work, but only up to a certain size, I am not sure what is the correct location or protocol for this large file.  I have to play it locally and securely, so SD storage is out.  The device will be offline, so using the internet is out to stream-download media.  I know it will be a large apk file and I will have to do my own distribution.

Any hints on what is the best way to get the large file working from a directory inside the app will be appreciated.

Using latest Visual studio community and cordova CLI 6.3

I am trying to get the large file to work on android.  The html5 video tag code is not really the issue, but is included below.  I am using videojs and works fine, just not the very large file.

*raw folder code*

```
  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster="images/oceans.png" data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
    <source src="android.resource://com.MYAPP.MYAPP/raw/myfile" type="video/mp4">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
  </video>
```

*assets folder code*

```
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster="images/oceans.png" data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
            <source src="videos/myfile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>      
    </video>
```

Comment: What does your code look like? If you've tried anything, edit your question to include it so we can more accurately help you fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I edited the question with the basic html5 video tag i am using.  To me the code is not really the issue, it seems to be more of where should I put this huge file and is there some technical limit I am missing preventing the file from loading for some reason.  large files work on SD card, and smaller files but not large file works from assets and raw folder.  That is the core discrepancy.

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? I also had a similar situation but unable to find a solution for local testing. Expansion files can be used after apk is uploaded to play store.

Comment: @NaumanRafique I have to use the devices SD card.  I cannot package video in the assets folder of the app because of the .apk 2GB storage limit.  I am using cordova-plugin-file to get SD storage location.